# Android Debuigging with Luna+Nexus 5+Android 5 fails

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-luna, nexus-5

I've upgraded my Nexus 5 to Android 5 and my SDK + plugins under Eclipse Luna. I can no longer debug on my android!

Application LogCat:

```
    11-26 18:10:54.474: I/art(5890): Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
    11-26 18:10:54.527: W/ActivityThread(5890): Application com.whizzthrough.android2 is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
    11-26 18:10:54.527: I/System.out(5890): Sending WAIT chunk
    11-26 18:10:54.533: I/art(5890): Debugger is active
    11-26 18:10:54.594: W/art(5890): GLITCH: unsupported modKind=MK_SOURCE_NAME_MATCH
    11-26 18:10:54.594: A/art(5890): art/runtime/jdwp/jdwp_request.cc:48] Check failed: p_ == end_ read too few bytes: 16
    11-26 18:10:54.727: I/System.out(5890): Debugger has connected
    11-26 18:10:54.727: I/System.out(5890): waiting for debugger to settle...
    11-26 18:10:54.750: A/art(5890): art/runtime/runtime.cc:284] Runtime aborting...
    11-26 18:10:54.750: A/art(5890): art/runtime/runtime.cc:284] Aborting thread:
    11-26 18:10:54.750: A/art(5890): art/runtime/runtime.cc:284] "JDWP" prio=5 tid=6         Runnable
    11-26 18:10:54.750: A/art(5890): art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x12c24080 self=0xaf30e400
    11-26 18:10:54.750: A/art(5890): art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   | sysTid=5900 nice=0 cgrp=apps sched=0/0 handle=0xac3a4d00
    11-26 18:10:54.750: A/art(5890): art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   | state=R schedstat=( 7059587 12507969 200 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=2 HZ=100
    11-26 18:10:54.750: A/art(5890): art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   | stack=0xb446b000-0xb446d000 stackSize=1012KB
    11-26 18:10:54.750: A/art(5890): art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   | held mutexes= "abort lock" "mutator lock"(shared held)
    11-26 18:10:54.750: A/art(5890): art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   native: #00 pc 00004c58  /system/lib/libbacktrace_libc++.so (UnwindCurrent::Unwind(unsigned int, ucontext*)+23)
    11-26 18:10:54.750: A/art(5890): art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   native: #01 pc 000034c1  /system/lib/libbacktrace_libc++.so (Backtrace::Unwind(unsigned int, ucontext*)+8)
    11-26 18:10:54.750: A/art(5890): art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   native: #02 pc 002526c5  /system/lib/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream >&, int, char const*, art::mirror::ArtMethod*)+84)
    11-26 18:10:54.750: A/art(5890): art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   native: #03 pc 002361a3  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream >&) const+162)
    11-26 18:10:54.750: A/art(5890): art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   native: #04 pc 00225b91  /system/lib/libart.so (art::AbortState::DumpThread(std::__1::basic_ostream >&, art::Thread*)+32)
    11-26 18:10:54.750: A/art(5890): art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   native: #05 pc 00225dfb  /system/lib/libart.so (art::AbortState::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream >&)+354)
    11-26 18:10:54.750: A/art(5890): art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   native: #06 pc 00225ff3  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort()+82)
    11-26 18:10:54.750: A/art(5890): art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   native: #07 pc 000a72e9  /system/lib/libart.so (art::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+1360)
    11-26 18:10:54.750: A/art(5890): art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   native: #08 pc 00198369  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JDWP::Request::CheckConsumed()+80)
    11-26 18:10:54.750: A/art(5890): art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   native: #09 pc 00193549  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JDWP::JdwpState::ProcessRequest(art::JDWP::Request&, art::JDWP::ExpandBuf*)+824)
    11-26 18:10:54.750: A/art(5890): art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]   native: #10 pc 0019561f  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JDWP::JdwpState::HandlePacket()+62)
```

Creating a simple app and debugging it on Android 4.1.2 works, on 5.0 the application close (crash) before the first line. Any help?